# Laravel-Infinite scroll but load data randomly on load without duplicate

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, infinite-scroll

I have problem on loading data with infinite scroll. I want to load data randomly when user load the page or refresh the page but my problem is when i use `inRandomOrder(1234)` data load without any order , but its static on main page.

for example the order is like 1,5,3,2,6,4 and its never changed

but i need to this order change on every load and refresh , if user refreshed the page , now see on this order (5,6,1,3,4,2) and next time (1,5,2,4,6,3)

Controller:

```
$data = Table::where('enabled', 1)->inRandomOrder(2)->paginate(6);
return view('home', ['data' => $data]);
```

Blade:

```
<div class="row scrolling-pagination">
      @foreach ($data as $v)
        @include('pages.main.card')
      @endforeach
  {{ $data->links() }}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.pagination').hide();
  $(function() {
      $('.scrolling-pagination').jscroll({
        loadingHtml: 'Loading...',
        autoTrigger: true,
        padding: 0,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
        contentSelector: 'div.scrolling-pagination',
        callback: function() {
            $('ul.pagination').remove();
          }
    });
  });
```

Im using [Jscroll](https://jscroll.com/) right now

Answer (score 1):

Argument you pass to `inRandomOrder()` is seed, so if passing static arg you will always get same results for same collection. You could use `rand()` to generate seed, and then save it inside session data. Although if you want to change order after user refreshes you would have to make some mechanism to regenerate this seed you save, every time user refreshes site.

```php
public function your_view_get_method(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->forget('randSeed');
    return view('home');
}

public function your_ajax_get_method(Request $request) {
    $seed = $request->session()->get('randSeed', rand());
    $data = Table::inRadnomOrder($seed)->paginate(6);
    $request->session()->put('randSeed', $seed);
    return $data;
}
```

This is how I would do it.

And if you want random set of data on every AJAX request, then just remove remove the argument at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you give me example? im new to laravel and also my english is not that good so its hard for me to understand xD thanks

Comment: `Table::inRandomOrder()->paginate(6);`
WIll give you random data every time.
`Table::inRandomOrder(1234)->paginate(6);`
Will give you always the same data.

Problem is, that when you have collection [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. And you use `Table::inRandomOrder()->paginate(3);` you may get duplicates on every load example: 1.`[1,6,7]` 2. `[4,1,9]` 3 `[6,2,9]`

Comment: So user on page will see it as [1,6,7,4,1,9,6,2,9, ...] - now quesiton is, whether its ok for you, or not?

Comment: no its not ok i dont want to show duplicates data

Comment: Thanks , is it possible if i create a random numbers array based on ids and then paginate them?. my array is (1,3,6,4,2,5) and eloquent return the result sort by my array then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232271/discussion-between-isoyost-and-alireza-behnamnik).